# Is "influence on" or "influence over" correct in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, expressions, exam-questions

> Despite being (a)\ a good teacher, (b)\ he has no influence on his pupil. (c)\ No error (d)

I am confused between option (c) and (d). I can't understand which phrase would be more appropriate, "influence on" or "influence over" in this context.

Can both of them be used interchangeably? In that case the answer would be (d).

Comment: Sunaina, welcome to ELL. So your question passes the "good question" test, you might want to put "influence over/influence on" in the title and try to tell us what you think they might mean, if different. :) https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that in practice, there is very little difference between "have no influence **on** somebody" and "have no influence **over** somebody".

Removing the *no*, it is typical to say "have **an** influence **on**" vs. "have influence **over**".

If somebody had an influence **on** me, it means I changed somehow because of that person. For example: *My friend had a positive influence on me, and I am now a better person as a result.*

If somebody has influence **over** someone or something, it means they have power to affect it. **Over** emphasizes the power imbalance, the fact that someone has authority.